# Adding a location field to buddypress activity

Tags: wordpress, geolocation, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields, buddypress

I am trying to figure out a way for adding location to buddypress activity. I tried using "Geo my WP" plugin to add location to a custom post type but the problem is that activity is not a custom post type. I couldn't add a custom field to it

I’m very basic with code so if someone can help me with how I can add a custom field to activities and have it get the location information from any 3rd party location plugin like "Geo my WP" or the simpler "IHS Geo Location"

Comment: If you are looking for a specific piece of code, you're best off picking the pieces that work the way you want (a specific geolocation plugin) and asking if anyone knows how to add its data to BuddyPress (or is willing to write it themselves). There are also tons of places (Envato Studio, Freelancer, Fiverr etc) where you can hire someone specifically to do so. What you're looking for isn't terribly complicated, and should be a pretty simple implementation.

Comment: Yeah u r righ, that's why I said I want to use the mentioned plugins for location and add the custom field myself to the activity. I'm just stuck to find the way to do that myself instead of hiring someone as I'm a beginner developer myself, hence asking for the help with that bit of code